# -bash: www.mydomain.com.pem: Permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, security, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have these three files in `/etc/nginx/ssl folder`:

```
www.mydomain.com.csr    
www.mydomain.com.key  
www.midomain.com.key.nopass
```

I bought and downloaded the positive ssl certs in `/etc/nginx/ssl/www_mydomain_com folder` these three files:

```
AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt  
PositiveSSLCA2.crt  
www_mydomain_com.crt
```

When I try install the signed certificate with this command:

```
sudo cat www_mydomain_com.crt PositiveSSLCA2.crt AddTrustExternalCaRoot.crt > www.mydomain.com.pem
```

I get this error:

```
-bash: www.mydomain.com.pem: Permission denied
```

**How can I fix this error and install my ssl?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cat www_mydomain_com.crt PositiveSSLCA2.crt AddTrustExternalCaRoot.crt > /tmp/www.mydomain.com.pem && sudo mv /tmp/www.mydomain.com.pem /etc/nginx/ssl/www_mydomain_com/
```

Yes, unprivileged user account. You don't get to have the sudo perm on '>' or pipes.

For example:

```
sudo echo "hey" > /usr/testing
sudo echo "hey" | touch /usr/testing
```

Comment: Thank you with this command, I get the error: `cat: AddTrustExternalCaRoot.crt: No such file or directory` The correct code is `cat www_mydomain_com.crt PositiveSSLCA2.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt > /tmp/www.mydomain.com.pem && sudo mv /tmp/www.mydomain.com.pem /etc/nginx/ssl/www_mydomain_com/` Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a file as a unprivileged user.

I would recommend the following,

cat the 3 files in a /tmp/www.mydomain.com location, then with sudo mv it to the correct place.